# docker run image diff not executing properly

Tags: docker

I'm having an issue with docker run syntax... I've tried these 2 commands and they both seem to generate the error message on the last line.

```
docker run --rm ${DOCKER_ARGS} -i ${BUILD_IMAGE} /bin/bash -c "diff /usr/local/bin/protoc /go/bin/protoc2"

docker run --rm ${DOCKER_ARGS} -i ${BUILD_IMAGE} diff /usr/local/bin/protoc /go/bin/protoc2

diff: /go/bin/protoc2/protoc: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something syntax-wise? I'm not sure why it's not running my command properly.

Comment: Is the file `/go/bin/protoc2/protoc` on host or inside container? Because it doesn't seem to be inside the container

Comment: Also check `/go/bin/protoc2` is a directory by any chance

Comment: `/go/bin/protoc2/protoc` doesn't exist. I'm trying to diff `/usr/local/bin/protoc` with `/go/bin/protoc2`  which is a binary. /go/bin/protoc2 was mounted with -v (which wasn't included).

Comment: I just ran `$ sudo cp /bin/ls /bin/ls2` and `$ docker run --rm -v /bin/ls2:/bin/ls2 ubuntu:16.04 diff /bin/ls /bin/ls2` and it gives me `Binary files /bin/ls and /bin/ls2 differ`. So I am pretty sure that your local mount doesn't exists and creates a directory. Change your run statement to this and add logs `docker run --rm ${DOCKER_ARGS} -i ${BUILD_IMAGE} /bin/bash -c "ls -alh /go/bin/protoc2 && diff /usr/local/bin/protoc /go/bin/protoc2"`

Comment: Yeah you're right, i made a really dumb mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo cp /bin/ls /bin/ls2
$ docker run --rm -v /bin/ls2:/bin/ls2 ubuntu:16.04 diff /bin/ls /bin/ls2
Binary files /bin/ls and /bin/ls2 differ.
```

So I am pretty sure that your local mount doesn't exists and creates a directory.

Change your run statement to

```
docker run --rm ${DOCKER_ARGS} -i ${BUILD_IMAGE} /bin/bash -c "ls -alh /go/bin/protoc2 && diff /usr/local/bin/protoc /go/bin/protoc2"
```

And you will know what is wrong